# __callStatic is not calling my non-static function

Tags: php

I thought this will work but it didn't.

```
class Foo {
    public function send($to, $message)
    {
        echo 'sending';
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $params)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(new static, $method), $params);
    }
}
```

When I do `Foo::send('mary','you had a little lamb')`, why is it still calling `Foo::send()` instead of `new Foo ->send($to, $message)`?

`Non-static method Foo::send() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic):

> __callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

Your method is not inaccessible, it exists and is accessible, it is just not static.